# Internet is not working on android emulator but working on ICS one

Tags: android, emulation

I have 3-4 emulators only out them the one running on API 14+ is running internet on default browser
while on other i am unable to connect to internet

I am not using any proxies in system

I have tried deleting and creating new emulators ...

I am on xp 32 bit running helios and updated sdk

Comment: Are you trying to use the browser on the emulator? Or are you trying to access internet via an application you are trying to develop?

Comment: yes i am accessing browser ...

Comment: have you added , android.permission.INTERNET ! in your manifest .

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the Emulator from the command line -

```
emulator -verbose -avd <AVD name>
```

This will give you detailed output and may show the error that's preventing the emulator from connecting to the Internet.

Comment: thanks ...I have tried this earlier ...but it doesn't show any warning except one for sensors
even the emulator is showing the E sign in notification..means its sort of connected

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are not on airplane mode, or have the data network mode deactivated on the emulator

Comment: I am not on airplane mode i checked and data is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Its random ..I cannot say this is the way ... I had previously tried deleting the emulator ...but this time i deleted all the emulators.
Created the new one 
Launched it from command line.
And IT WORKS!!!